# JQuery alternate colors of *groups of rows* in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple TBODY elements (one for each month in a year) and would like to alternate row colors *within the TBODY element*.

For illustration, I have a table with the following basic structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>October</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>1400</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>November</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  ... a <tbody> for all 12 months ...
</table>
```

And the following JQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("table > tbody > tr:even").addClass("alternate-row");
    });
</script>
```

But what happens is JQuery treats the **entire table** as one logical group and applies the alternate-row class to every odd row *regardless of TBODY* location.

In other words, what I want is:

```
October (normal color)
  Item #1 (normal color)
  Item #2 (alt color)
  Item #3 (normal color)
November (normal color)
  Item #1 (normal color)
  Item #2 (alt color)
  Item #3 (normal color)
... etc
```

Instead what I'm getting with the above JQuery is:

```
October (alt color)
  Item #1 (normal color)
  Item #2 (alt color)
  Item #3 (normal color)
November (alt color)
  Item #1 (normal color)
  Item #2 (alt color)
  Item #3 (normal color)
... etc
```

In other words, it doesn't recognize the TBODY selector for some reason. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It normal because $("table > tbody > tr:even") return all TR that are in a TBODY which is itself in a TABLE. JQuery will not do any distinction for your TR with month or not. You have to make a more complex styling. You can iterate on your TBODY with $("table > tbody").each() and then create a sub function in the each to manage all your TR of the current TBODY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, this might be what you want:

```
$("table > tbody").each( function() {
    $("tr:even:not(:first)", this).addClass("alternate-row");
} );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnfEq/)

Problem with your code is selecting all TRs at once.

Comment: That's not a problem. I mean Dave's code is working fine, and it selects the even rows as expected.

Comment: @AlecTMH Rows should be alternated in the scope of single `tbody`. If you [add one row](http://jsfiddle.net/wncNm/1/), I think the result is not what Dave wants.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean.

Comment: This was it exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the OP's original 'What I want'

Solution looks more like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("tbody").find("tr:even:not(:first)").addClass("alternate-row");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/pcDBG/)